# Delete data in php from same page mysqli

Tags: php

I am not able to delete data from database from php

here is my code

```
        <tbody>
        <form action='<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>'method='GET'>

         <?php
          include 'config.php';

          $sql="SELECT * from department";
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
          if($result->num_rows > 0 )
           {
             while ($row= $result-> fetch_assoc()){
             echo "<tr><td>". $row["id"] ."</td><td><b>". $row["department_name"] ."</b></td><td>
             <a href='?id=" . $row["id"] . "'><input type='submit' class='btn cur-p btn-danger' name='delete_department' value='delete'></a><td></tr></form>";
           } 
          echo"</tbody>";
         }
         else {
             echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>No Data Found !</div";
         }
         $conn-> close();
         ?>
```

PHP CODE

```
      <?php  
     // connect to the database
     include('config.php');

    // confirm that the 'id' variable has been set
    if(isset($_GET['delete_department']))
  {
      // get the 'id' variable from the URL
          $id = $_GET['id'];

         // delete record from database
      if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM department WHERE id = ? 
     LIMIT 1"))
          $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
        $stmt->execute();
         $stmt->close();
      }
       else
           {
        echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
     }
       $mysqli->close();


       }


        ?>
```

What is the Correct PHP code for deleting an entry ?
Config seems ok to me.

Comment: missing {}  after   if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM department WHERE id = ? 
     LIMIT 1"))

Answer (score 1):

This is your resulting HTML:

```
<a href='?id=123'><input type='submit' class='btn cur-p btn-danger' name='delete_department' value='delete'></a>
```

Which doesn't really make sense.  You're trying to put a submit button *in a link*.  Links are already clickable, you don't need a *button* to make one.  Since you're getting the value from the query string collection, just add what you need to the query string on the link URL:

```
<a href='?id=123&delete_department=1'>Delete</a>
```

Which in your code might look like this:

```
echo "<tr><td>". $row["id"] ."</td><td><b>". $row["department_name"] ."</b></td><td>
<a href='?id=" . $row["id"] . "&delete_department=1'>Delete</a><td></tr></form>";
```

Note that you may indeed have *more* errors I haven't spotted.  The code is poorly formatted and difficult to spot typos, but [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794330/delete-data-in-php-from-same-page-mysqli/49794412#comment86603042_49794330) claims to have spotted at least one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dbHost     = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName     = "csvupload";

// Create database connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);


// Check the connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Delete a record
$id =  $_GET['id']; // ID of the record to delete
//$user_id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM members WHERE id=$id";

print_r($sql);
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully.";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}

// Close the connection
$conn->close();
?>

Frontend: <a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your PHP code to:

```
include('config.php');

if (isset($_GET['delete_department'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM department WHERE id = :id "))
    $stmt->bind_param(":id", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
} else {
echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: His previous way of `->prepare` was valid and now you've broke it. You're thinking of pdo `bindParam` when this is [mysqli bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) !

Comment: @RahulKumarSharma Please look at David's answer as the others are incorrect solutions.